# PrimeNg Multiselect widget is not working in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

PrimeNG Multiselect widget is not working properly. I tried with the basic one it gives a broken view. But it works on my other projects. Anyone had an issue like this and came up with a solution?
I also tried npm reinstall. I have attached a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eOCE.jpg)

Comment: Is the css imported?

Comment: please provide the code you used, i am sure there is some styling issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had to manually add the primeNg css file in the angular.json. cli didn't work